# Rails Api Returning ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find User) except the User is in the DB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js

I have a rails 6 API (Backend) running a Vue & Flutter Frontend,

When I try to pass my user credentials to the API from Vue I am getting the following error:

```
app/controllers/signin_controller.rb:6:in `create'
Started POST "/signin" for ::1 at 2019-11-13 02:51:58 -0700
Processing by SigninController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"user"=>{"email"=>"xxxxxx@xxxxxx.co", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" IS NULL LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/signin_controller.rb:5:in `create'
Completed 404 Not Found in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 2.1ms | Allocations: 3220)



ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find User):

app/controllers/signin_controller.rb:5:in `create'
```

now I can go into my rails console and the User dose exist with the MATCHING email address.

I am not too sure what to do to get this user found and signed in.

I am using JWT Sessions to handle the tokens and axios to make the calls to the api.

here is my signin controller create action.

```
  def create
    user = User.find_by!(email: params[:email])
    if user.authenticate(params[:password])
      payload = { user_id: user.id }
      session = JWTSessions::Session.new(payload: payload, refresh_by_access_allowed: true)
      tokens = session.login
      response.set_cookie(JWTSessions.access_cookie,
                        value: tokens[:access],
                        httponly: true,
                        secure: Rails.env.production?)
      render json: { csrf: tokens[:csrf] }
    else
      not_authorized
    end
  end
```

and here is the full method I am sending from vue:

```
   signin () {
      let formData = new FormData()
      formData.append('user[email]', this.user.email)
      formData.append('user[password]', this.user.password)

      this.$http.plain.post('/signin', formData, {emulateJSON: true})
        .then(response => this.signinSuccessful(response))
        .catch(error => this.signinFailed(error))
    },
    signinSuccessful (response) {
      if (!response.data.csrf) {
        this.signinFailed(response)
        return
      }
      localStorage.csrf = response.data.csrf
      localStorage.signedIn = true
      this.$router.replace('/dashboard')
    },
    signinFailed (error) {
      this.error = (error.response && error.response.data && error.response.data.error) || ''
      delete localStorage.csrf
      delete localStorage.signedIn
    },
    checkSignedIn () {
      if (localStorage.signedIn) {
        this.$router.replace('/dashboard')
      }
    }
  }
```

Any assistance here would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you paste what your `params` object in your controller looks like please? It's probably an issue with how the `[:email]` key is namespaced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the request log we can see that the parameters coming in to your controller are:

```
Parameters: {"user"=>{"email"=>"xxxxxx@xxxxxx.co", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
```

We can also see query that is made to the database:

```
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" IS NULL LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
```

Especially

```
WHERE "users"."email" IS NULL
```

So the email you're passing into the query is nil. 
You should find the user like this instead

```
User.find_by!(email: params[:user][:email])
```

Or preferably

```
def create
  user = User.find_by!(email: user_params[:email])
  ...
end

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password)
end
```